# JOB SEQUENCING resolution with MIP (using pulp)

Tags: python-3.x, pulp

*Hello,*

I'm trying to make an algorithm with pulp to resolve a JOB SEQUENCING problem. I know that it is not the best way to use a MIP solver to resolve JOB SEQUENCING, however it's just for training.

But my code it's not good and doesn't produce the good solution(full 0).
So if someone helpful can have a look. Thank you !

```
import numpy 
import pulp
import time


# Work must me achieve before :
deadline=[2,4,3,7,10]
# Score of each work :
score = [10,30,20,50,20]
# Time to do the work :
time=[2,2,2,5,3]
# Just works index :
works = [0,1,2,3,4]

tMax = max(deadline)
nItem = len(deadline)

# Create (item, time) variables
s = [(i,j) for i in range(0,nItem) for j in range(0,tMax)]

prob = pulp.LpProblem("Job_Sequencing_Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)
wk = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Works", s,lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

# We want to maximize the score 
prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,j)]*score[i] for i in range (0,nItem) for j in range(0,tMax)])

# Respect deadline constraints
for i in range (0,nItem):
    for j in range(0,tMax):
        # j represent time(or step) where we are
        # If we are at t=3 and the object takes 2 sec to compile
        # but the deadline is t=4 it's not good
        if j>(deadline[i]-time[i]):
            prob+=pulp.lpSum(wk[(i,j)])==0 

for i in range(0,nItem):
    # Works can only be done once
    prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,j)] for j in range(0,tMax)]) <=1
    # We must add time to achieve work constraint
    for j in range(0,tMax):
        # If the sum of time to achive work of before jobs, are greater than the current time who we
        # are, it's not good, so we add this constraint
        timeToFinishPreviousWork = 0
        for x in range(0,tMax-1):
            for y in range(0,nItem):
                timeToFinishPreviousWork += wk[(y,x)]*time[y]
        # wk[(i,j)]*(j+1) = current t 
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(wk[(i,j)]*(j+1)) >= timeToFinishPreviousWork

prob.solve()
for i in range(0,nItem):
    for j in range(0,tMax):
        print("%s = %f" % (wk[(i,j)], pulp.value(wk[(i,j)])))
```

Comment: I think your main problem is to do with the `timeToFinishPreviousWork` variable and how it is used in setting constratints. This variable depends on problem decision variables (`wk`), and so needs to be an auxillary problem variable itself. In fact there needs to be one for each `i` and for each `j`.

Comment: Hi, I think you're right, I must change this with an if else condition but it don't works to. I put the new code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution :)
Return:

```
Worker_(2,_0) = 1
Worker_(3,_2) = 1
Worker_(4,_9) = 1
```

Note: time j is no minimize, because it must put `Worker_(4,_7) = 1` instead

```
import numpy 
import pulp
import time


# Work must me achieve before :
deadline=[4,4,3,7,13]
# Score of each work :
score = [10,30,60,60,20]
# Time to do the work :
time=[2,2,2,5,3]
# Just worker index :
worker = [0,1,2,3,4]

M=100000
tMax = max(deadline)
nItem = len(deadline)

# Create (item, time) variables
s = [(i,j) for i in range(0,nItem) for j in range(0,tMax)]

prob = pulp.LpProblem("Job_Sequencing_Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)
wk = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Worker", s,lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

omega = [(i,j) for i in range(0,nItem) for j in range(0,tMax)]
c = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Omega", s,lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

# We want to maximize the score 
prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,j)]*score[i] for i in range (0,nItem) for j in range(0,tMax)])

# Respect deadline constraints
for i in range (0,nItem):
    for j in range(0,tMax):
        # j represent time(or step) where we are
        # If we are at t=3 and the object takes 2 sec to compilate
        # but the deadline is t=4 it's note good
        if j>(deadline[i]-time[i]):
            prob+=pulp.lpSum(wk[(i,j)])==0 

for j in range(0,tMax):
    prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,j)] for i in range (0,nItem)]) <=1


prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,0)] for i in range(0,nItem)]) ==1



for i in range(0,nItem):
    # Works can only be done once
    prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,j)] for j in range(0,tMax)]) <=1
    # We must add time to achieve work constraint
    for j in range(0,tMax):
        # If the sum of time to achive work of before jobs, are greater than the current time who we
        # are, it's not good, so we add this constraint
        timeToFinishPreviousWork = 0
        # j=-1 to count only previous job(not current)
        for x in range(0,j):
            for y in range(0,nItem):
                timeToFinishPreviousWork += wk[(y,x)]*time[y]
        # wk[(i,j)]*(j+1) = current t 
        # if timeToFinishPreviousWork > wk[(i,j)]*j(represent current time)  then  wk[(i,j)]=0
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(timeToFinishPreviousWork) >=wk[(i,j)]*(j) -M*(1-c[(i,j)])
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(timeToFinishPreviousWork) <=wk[(i,j)]*(j) +M*(c[(i,j)])
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(0-M*(1-c[(i,j)])) <= wk[(i,j)]
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(0+M*(1-c[(i,j)])) >= wk[(i,j)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change timeToFinishPreviousWork constrait with an if else, but still doesn't work. I used this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500415/how-to-write-if-else-statement-in-linear-programming/2501007

I would like to says that if the current time is inferior than the time to do previous job then it's not possible so variable equals 0

```
import numpy 
import pulp
import time


# Work must me achieve before :
deadline=[4,4,3,7,10]
# Score of each work :
score = [10,30,20,50,20]
# Time to do the work :
time=[2,2,2,5,3]
# Just worker index :
worker = [0,1,2,3,4]

M=100000
tMax = max(deadline)
nItem = len(deadline)

# Create (item, time) variables
s = [(i,j) for i in range(0,nItem) for j in range(0,tMax)]

prob = pulp.LpProblem("Job_Sequencing_Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)
wk = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Worker", s,lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

omega = [(i,j) for i in range(0,nItem) for j in range(0,tMax)]
c = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Omega", s,lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

# We want to maximize the score 
prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,j)]*score[i] for i in range (0,nItem) for j in range(0,tMax)])

# Respect deadline constraints
for i in range (0,nItem):
    for j in range(0,tMax):
        # j represent time(or step) where we are
        # If we are at t=3 and the object takes 2 sec to compilate
        # but the deadline is t=4 it's note good
        if j>(deadline[i]-time[i]):
            prob+=pulp.lpSum(wk[(i,j)])==0 

for j in range(0,tMax):
    prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,j)] for i in range (0,nItem)]) <=1


for i in range(0,nItem):
    # Works can only be done once
    prob+=pulp.lpSum([wk[(i,j)] for j in range(0,tMax)]) <=1
    # We must add time to achieve work constraint
    for j in range(0,tMax):
        # If the sum of time to achive work of before jobs, are greater than the current time who we
        # are, it's not good, so we add this constraint
        timeToFinishPreviousWork = 0
        # j=-1 to count only previous job(not current)
        for x in range(0,j-1):
            for y in range(0,nItem):
                timeToFinishPreviousWork += wk[(y,x)]*time[y]
        # wk[(i,j)]*(j+1) = current t 
        # if timeToFinishPreviousWork > wk[(i,j)]*j(represent current time)  then  wk[(i,j)]=0
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(timeToFinishPreviousWork) >=wk[(i,j)]*(j+1) -M*(1-c[(i,j)])
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(timeToFinishPreviousWork) <=wk[(i,j)]*(j+1) +M*(c[(i,j)])
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(0-M*(1-c[(i,j)])) <= wk[(i,j)]
        prob+=pulp.lpSum(0+M*(1-c[(i,j)])) >= wk[(i,j)]


prob.solve()
for i in range(0,nItem):
    for j in range(0,tMax):
        print("%s = %d" % (wk[(i,j)], pulp.value(wk[(i,j)])))
```